# SQL query to return the latest date when the column has changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `per_all_assignments_m` paam that has position_id and other object ids. This table has effetive_start_Date and effective_end_date.
Whenever there is an update in this table, the effective_start_Date changes to the date when the change was made.

```
assignment_number    person_id             eff_start_Date         eff_end_date         POSISTION_ID    GRADE_ID        
E12                   12                     12-JAN-2020           31-DEC-4712           10                 2         
E12                   12                     25-NOV-2019           11-JAN-2020           10                 2         
E12                   12                     02-APR-2019           24-NOV-2019           8                  2
---
E11                   11                    12-JAN-2020           31-DEC-4712           10                 2         
E11                   11                     25-NOV-2019           11-JAN-2020           10                 2         
E11                   11                     02-APR-2019           24-NOV-2019           10                  2
```

The below query will not return anything for PREv_Job_TItle since there is no change in position_id in the latest 2 rows.

I want to fetch another column in the below query -  cur_eff_dt. If there is no change in the latest rows as of trunc(sysdate) in the PAAM table,
then the cur_eff_dt should return the last date when the position_id was changed or the first date that position was tagged to the employee.
From the above table - cur_eff_dt should be 25-Nov-2019 for employee E12.  FOR Employee number - E11 it should be 02-APR-2019.

Any function through which this can be achieved ?

```
    select distinct 
PAPF.PERSON_NUMBER, 
    NULLIF((select distinct name
from   (
  select distinct m.person_id,m.position_id,h.name,
         lead(m.position_id,1,0) over (order by m.position_id) as nextr ,
         lag(m.position_id,1,0) over (order by m.position_id) as prevr        
  from   per_all_assignments_M m,HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F F,hr_all_positions_f_vL h
  where m.position_id=f.position_id
             and f.position_id=h.position_id
 and sysdate between h.effective_start_date and h.effective_end_date
and m.person_id=papf.person_id
and h.effective_end_date=TO_DATE('12/31/4712 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
where nextr<>prevr and rownum=1),POS.NAME)PREv_Job_TItle,
     POS.NAME Current_job_title


from    per_all_people_f PAPF
        ,PER_PERSON_NAMES_F PPNF
        ,PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE PPOS
        ,PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM
        ,PER_PERSON_TYPES PPT
        ,PER_GRADES_F_TL PGF
        ,hr_all_positions_f_vL POS
        ,PER_JOBS_F PJF


where   1=1
and papf.person_number = '111'

        AND PPOS.PERSON_ID =PAPF.PERSON_ID
        AND PPOS.PERSON_ID=PPNF.PERSON_ID
        AND PPNF.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
        AND PAAM.PERSON_ID=PAPF.PERSON_ID
        AND PPOS.PERSON_ID=PAAM.PERSON_ID
        AND PPOS.LEGISLATION_CODE=PAAM.LEGISLATION_CODE
        AND PAAM.PRIMARY_ASSIGNMENT_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E' 
        AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y'
        AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE = 'ACTIVE'
        AND PAAM.PRIMARY_FLAG='Y'
        AND PAAM.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID = PPOS.PERIOD_OF_SERVICE_ID
        AND PGF.GRADE_ID(+)=  PAAM.GRADE_ID
        AND PGF.LANGUAGE='US'
        AND POS.POSITION_ID(+)=PAAM.POSITION_ID
        AND PJF.JOB_ID(+)=PAAM.JOB_ID
                        AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE=TO_DATE('12/31/4712 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE

        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PGF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PGF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
        AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN POS.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND POS.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your current query but you can achieve what is required using following query:

```
Select person_id, assignment_number,
       Max(effective_start_date) keep (dense_rank last order by rn) as cut_off_date
From
(Select t.*, 
        case when lead(position_id) 
          over (partition by person_id, assignment_number order by effective_start_date)
        <> position_id then 1 else 0 end as rn
From per_all_assigments_m t
Where person_id in (11,12))
Group by person_id, assignment_number
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is giving the latest effective start date of the previous position id and not the least effective start date of the latest position id. If we take the above example - it is giving 02-APR-2019  for E12 and it should be 25-NOV-2019